# Concatenating string with String Builder?

Tags: c#

I want to generate a string with a format

*'abc','avc',abc','avc',abc','avc','abc','avc',abc','avc',abc','avc','abc','avc'*

The value can be anything or it can be empty.This is my code

```
        string sep = "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(var l in label.Rows)
        {
            sb.Append(sep).Append(l.Text);
            sep = ",''";
        }
```

this returns me

*abc,''abc,''abc,''abc,''abc,''abc,''abc,''abc,''abc,''abc,''abc,''abc,''abc,''abc,''abc*

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: And what problem did you get with that code?

Comment: You really want your string to start with  `,`?

Comment: _"I think I can't make the logic"_ What is the logic?

Comment: @Magnus it doesn't

Comment: @J.vanLangen no? `,'abc','avc',abc......`

Comment: I've edited sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: @Magnus `sep` is first assign to `""`  ;-)

Comment: @J.vanLangen I was talking about the desired output which started with `,` which you can see in the history of the question. Not the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course using Linq will be simpler and more readable, but if you want to know what has gone wrong in your code then

```
// Start with the initial quote
string sep = "'";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var l in label.Rows)
{
    sb.Append(sep).Append(l.Text);
    // Quote before and after the comma
    sep = "','";
}
// You need an additional quote to close the string if there is any
if(sb.Length > 0)
   sb.Append("'");
```

Consider also that StringBuilder is not always faster than a simple concatenation. If this code is performance sensitive I would try to measure what happen if you use a single *sb.Append(sep + l.Text)* instead of calling two times the Append method

Answer (score 3):

More simple with LinQ and [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) `Join`

```
string s = string.Join(",", label.Rows.Select(l => $"'{l.Text}'"));
```